# Some inline images won't show

Tags: org-mode, inline-image

This is a weird problem, and I can't see to find an answer anywhere. I have a file with 5 images that I want to show inline. I'm sure this worked for me yesterday, but today I can not make it work.

If I toggle inline mode, `C-c C-x C-v`, I get the message `2 images displayed inline`. However, I can click the three other links, and the images open in new buffers. I can also export the document to PDF using LaTeX, and the images show.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess you could `edebug-eval-defun` on `org-toggle-inline-images` and step through it, and maybe that would show you what's going on and why it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be really simple. In fact I was just being stupid.

When I viewed my document I realized that the images that didn't show were missing the double square brackets before and after the image links. I guess the reason I didn't notice this in the beginning is that the square brackets also didn't occur for the images that showed:
[image: org-mode1]

...until I tried to delete part of the line:
[image: org-mode2]